# Output of command executed with Paramiko invoke_shell() is paginated (getting "--more--" in recv)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, channel

I have a command `XYZ` sent over a channel using the `sendall()`

```
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
channel.sendall('XYZ\n')
response = channel.recv(2000)
```

I should have the entire output right there, but then I notice that in the last line of the output that I do receive, there is a `--more--` at the end. Like the one that you get when you use the `less` command.

As a result, the channel is still waiting for more output because the buffer is not empty (more output is expected) and the command is expecting me to press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to display more of the output.

The channel just waits forever.

How do I get the entire output in one go? I do not want that `--more--`.

Increasing the buffer size makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command), not the `invoke_shell` + `sendall`.

The `invoke_shell` (with default arguments) emulates an interactive 80x24 terminal. What makes the command you are executing do fancy stuff like pagination.

```
def invoke_shell(self, term='vt100', width=80, height=24, width_pixels=0,
                 height_pixels=0):
```

While the `exec_command` (with default arguments, namely the `get_pty=False`) uses a non-interactive terminal. What should make the command (if implemented properly) avoid doing pagination.

```
def exec_command(self, command, bufsize=-1, timeout=None, get_pty=False):
```

---

If the above does not help with removing the `--more--`, and you are connecting to a Cisco device, sending the following command to the device may help:

```
terminal length 0
```

See also [How to proceed with the word "MORE" to get to the end of the command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60704144/850848).